# $y=(x+1)/(x-1)$ rearrange to make $x$ the subject

Tags: linear-algebra

**Sorry for low-level question**

$y=(x+1)/(x-1)$

I got $x = (1+y)/(1-y)$
but the answers that I got with the question says it is $(1+y)/ (y-1)$

I've repeated the question many times in case I messed up on something simple.

Comment: Do you mean $y=(x+1)/(x-1)$?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit that now.

Comment: Your TeX was suffering from a surfeit of dollar signs; I have removed the redundant ones.

Comment: Incidentally, it's curious that the answer key should say $(1+y)/(y-1)$ instead of $(y+1)/(y-1)$. I prefer the latter, since it is of the same form as the original equation. Indeed, the fact that $x$ and $y$ appear to simply switch places shows that the function is symmetrical about the $x=y$ diagonal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's do the motions:
$$
y = \frac{x+1}{x-1}\\
(x-1)y = x+1\\
xy-y = x+1\\
xy-x = 1+y\\
x(y-1) = 1+y\\
x = \frac{1+y}{y-1}
$$
I don't know which step you did which introduced the sign error (it could be basically anything, including copying the original problem wrong), but the answer key was right.

Answer (score 2):

There is also this solution.

\begin{align}
   y &= \frac{x + 1}{x - 1} \\
   y - 1 &= \frac{2}{x - 1} \\
   x - 1 &= \frac{2}{y - 1} \\
   x &= \frac{y + 1}{y - 1}
\end{align}